# How do you generate an AWS Signature in ReadyAPI/SoapUI

Tags: soapui, readyapi, aws

I am trying to perform a GET of an object on S3 storage using ReadyAPI (or SoapUI).

[Here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectGET.html) is the documentation for how it is done

In order to make the request I require a "signature" to be generated.  How can this be done within the ReadyAPI suite itself?

p.s. The AWS API plugin [doesn't currently function for my region](https://github.com/SmartBear/ready-aws-plugin/issues/3) (eu-west-1)

Answer (score 2):

This is really easy if the use of the AWS JDK is an option for you.  I tried many hours to generate my own signature for REST API access to AWS.  After I discovered the AWS JDK it was a matter of minutes.  All can be done with a few lines of groovy script code within ReadyAPI/SoapUI NG.

- Download, install, configure AWS CLI. (why this?  If you configure your secret key in the CLI, the JDK will recognize the configuration and configuration location on your computer and use it)
- Be on latest version of ReadyAPI/SoapUI
- Download AWS JDK and unzip
- Copy aws-java-sdk-x.xx.xx.jar to your ReadyAPI/SoapUI installation Lib folder and restart ReadyAPI/SoapUI
- Groovy script step code utilizing AWS JDK to list buckets that you have access to(commented out stuff would let you create buckets):

  ```
  import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
  import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
  import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
  import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
  import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
  import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
  import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
  import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CreateBucketRequest;
  import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListBucketsRequest;
  import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.GetBucketLocationRequest;


  def AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
  //s3client.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2));

  try {
  //   def String bucketName     = "soapui-bucket";
  //   if(!(s3client.doesBucketExist(bucketName))) {
  //      // Note that CreateBucketRequest does not specify region. So bucket is created in the region specified in the client.
  //      s3client.createBucket(new CreateBucketRequest(bucketName));
  //   };

     // Get location.
  //   String bucketLocation = s3client.getBucketLocation(new GetBucketLocationRequest(bucketName));
  //   log.info("bucket location = " + bucketLocation);

     // A couple of ways to list buckets.
     bucketList = s3client.listBuckets();
     log.info("bucketList All= " + bucketList);
  //   bucketList = s3client.listBuckets(new ListBucketsRequest());
  //   log.info("bucketList Owner= " + bucketList);

  }
  catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
              log.info("Caught an AmazonServiceException, which " +
                      "means your request made it " +
                      "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response" +
                      " for some reason.");
              log.info("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
              log.info("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
              log.info("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
              log.info("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
              log.info("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
  }
  catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
              log.info("Caught an AmazonClientException, which " +
                      "means the client encountered " +
                      "an internal error while trying to " +
                      "communicate with S3, " +
                      "such as not being able to access the network.");
              log.info("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
  }

  log.info 'Test Step "' + testRunner.runContext.currentStep.name + '" done...';
  ```